# COMO FAZER UM GetAsync em uma API ASP.NET passando um objeto como parâmetro?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

Gostaria de saber como faço para enviar um objeto como parâmetro para uma API feita em ASP.NET e retornar dados pela mesma?

Entendo que o método simples de um Get é:

```
HttpClient cliente = new HttpClient();

string url = "http://localhost:50501/api/values/ListaContatos";   
var response = await cliente.GetStringAsync(url);               
var contatos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Contato>>(response);

return contatos;
```

... Como eu faria para enviar um objeto e retornar dados?

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo assim:

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{                
    var url = new Uri("http://localhost:50501/api/values/ListaContatos?id=1&nome=teste");
    var result = http.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)                {

        return null;
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(resultContent);
}
```